# whitespace in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

Pattern that doesn't allow whitespace at the begining. Please find the code below :

```
<input class="mdl-textfield__input inputMaterial"  maxlength="100" 
[(ngModel)]="getEmpName[i]" (keydown)="onKeyPress($event)" pattern="[a-zA-Z 
]*" appFloatLabelDirective="" formControlName="employer_name">
```

Comment: your pattern just allows regular characters inside the string, try to precise beginning and end of string like this `^[a-zA-Z]*$` (to specify that no other things can be allowed between start and end of the string)

Comment: Will using `trim()` help you? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

Comment: ^[^-\s][\w\s-]+$ - is what helped me. It accepts everything except for blank space and white space at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^[^-\s][\w\s-]+$ - this pattern helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the angular `input-mask` plugin for this kind of problem : https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks

It allows you to filter inputs, and create custom directives